# Preview Keeps freezing - not responding

Tags: macos, preview

I am using preview on macOS Sierra. Whenever I try to open a pdf, jpg etc it keeps freezing and I have to force quit it.

I have deleted `Containers/com.apple.Preview`

and restarted but am still having the same issue.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the following files and it fixed the issue

```
Containers/com.apple.Preview

Containers/com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper

Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState
```